# In which cases is the dynamic CRT not already initialized on call to user supplied DllMain?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, msvcrt, dllmain

*Preamble:* This question is specifically concerned with, and only with, the behavior of the *dynamic* CRT used through `/MD`. It does not question the validity of any other recommendations wrt. `DllMain`.

---

As [we've been told](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx#general_best_practices): (ref: Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices, MSDN, May 17, 2006)

> You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain:
>
> - ...
> - Use the memory management function from the *dynamic* C Run-Time (CRT). If the CRT DLL is not initialized, calls to these functions can cause the process to crash.
> - ...

Others [have questioned this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27383635/321013) already (as in: questioned the validity of the argument) and since we helpfully get an answer there, we can clearly see one rather *simple* case where this could [potentially cause troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27385139/321013):

> You are working from the assumption that the entrypoint for a DLL is always _DllMainCRTStartup. This is not the case, it is merely the linker's default. It can be anything a programmer wants it to be, swiftly and easily changed with the linker's /ENTRYPOINT option. There is nothing that Microsoft can do to prevent this.

So these are the elements of this question:

- **Is there *any other* situation when linking [`/MD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) and *not* supplying a custom `/ENTRYPOINT`, where the *dynamic* CRT ought to not be fully initialized?**

  - Specifically, if all DLL loading only done through "static dependencies", i.e. no explicit `LoadLibrary`calls at all, just link time DLL dependencies.
- Bonus: The MS docs specifically call out *"memory management function"*, but as far as I can tell, if the CRT is not initialized, potentially *any* CRT function should be unsafe. Why call out memory management functions in this way?
- No.3:

  Wrt. to the custom `ENTRYPOINT`: I don't quite see how this can be such an important scenario that it need be included in the not-do-in-DllMain list without further qualification. *IFF* I supply a custom entry point, I'm responsible for correctly initializing the CRT, or the *CRT will not work properly anywhere in my program*, not just DllMain. Why call out the DllMain part specifically?

  This leads me back to Q.1, namely if this is the only scenario where this is problematic for the *dynamic* CRT. A clarification or eye-opener why this would be more important for DllMain that for other parts of the DLL, or what I might miss here, would be appreciated.

---

Bonus links:

- [When are global objects constructed and destructed by Visual C++?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141017-00/?p=43823)
- [DllMain : a horror story](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oleglv/2003/10/28/dllmain-a-horror-story/)
- [Calling LoadLibrary from DllMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370812/calling-loadlibrary-from-dllmain)

---

<sub>**Rationale:** I feel I should add this for context: I am asking this because we have *massive* amounts of code doing things via global C++ object constructors. Things that actually broke have been vetted out over the years (like concurrent `LoadLibrary`, thread sync, etc.), but all the code is full of `std` C++ and CRT functions, that happily have been working for years on Windows XP, 7 and Windows 10 without any known hiccups. While I'm *not* one to cry "but it just works", I have to do an engineering judgment here on whether there is any short-to-medium value in trying to "fix" this. Therefore, I would appreciate if the soapbox answers could be left in their boxes.</sub>

Comment: VS forum thread wrt - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69c08c88-56b9-42ae-8a46-e4301d2f6161/crt-initialization-and-dllmain?forum=vcgeneral -- maybe an answer there.

Comment: I don't understand what bonus questions are. In what way are they bonus? Who gets the bonus and what is it? Or is it just an excuse to ask more than one question when you know that's against the guidelines?

Comment: if your dll loaded not recursive (not inside another dll load call flow) the crt dlls will be guarantee initialized (it entry points called) before your dll entry point (absolute unrelated here what is entry point of your dll). problem can potentially be only in case if your dll recursively loaded: somebody call `LoadLibrary` for your dll from dll entry point or your dll was inject external, during load dlls process. if crt dll already loaded, but yet not initialized at this time, depend from os version (before win8.1) can be really your ep called before crt ep

Comment: I agree with @RbMm here. I am trying to mentally construct a scenario where the 'msvcrt.dll' DllMain has not been called when a dll, with a dependency on it is initialised. Excluding circular dependency issues when a dll depends on another dll, that other dll is always completely initialised (via dll main).
This assumes of course that the dll CRT initialises itself in its DllMain.

Comment: @ChrisBecke - really exist case when `LoadLibrary` for dll is called inside another dll entry point (for example `AppInit_DLLs`, dll use as shim dll via shimengine, injected from driver when some another dll mapped..) - in this case *msvcrt.dll* (for example) can be already loaded in process, but it entry point yet not called. and at this time - your dll, which depend on *msvcrt.dll* is loaded.. then different windows - different process this situation. on win7 and early - your dll entry point will be called **before** *msvcrt.dll* in this case

Comment: however this is only is problem for dll special designed recursive load and usually at very early stage of process startup (like *AppInit_DLLs*). for dlls which load in usual way(not recursive) and not designed for injection - the crt dlls entry points guarantee will be called before our dll entry point and we can use it in own dll entry point already

Comment: @RbMm - so you would say it cannot happen in any "standard application" scenario?

Comment: @MartinBa - yes, if your dll not loaded via `LoadLibrary` (`LdrLoadDll`) when another load dll active (or initialize process phase, when exe decencies is loaded ) - it (crt dll yet not initialized) this can not happens. also in latest windows versions the loader implementation is changed - now it can not happen under any flow at all. a *DllMain : a horror story* already can not be reproduced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other situation when linking `/MD` and not supplying a
>   custom `/ENTRYPOINT`, where the dynamic CRT ought to not be fully
>   initialized?

first some notation:

- **X** have static import (depends on) **Y** and **Z** : `X[ Y, Z]`
- **X** entry point : `X_DllMain`
- `X_DllMain` call `LoadLibrary(Y)` : `X<Y>`

when we use `/MD` - we use crt in separate DLL(s). initialized in this context mean that entry point(s) of crt DLL(s) already called. so question can be more general and clear:

are from `X[Y]` *=>* `Y_DllMain` called before `X_DllMain` ?

in general case no. because can be circular dependency, when `Y[X]` or `Y[Z[X]]`.

most known example `user32[gdi32]`, and `gdi32[user32]` or in win10 depends on `gdi32[gdi32full[user32]]` . so `user32_DllMain` or `gdi32_DllMain` must be called first ? however obvious that any crt DLL(s) not depends on our custom DLL. so let exclude circular dependency case.

when loader load module **X** - it load all it dependency modules (and it dependency - this is recursive process), if it already not in memory, then loader build call graph, and begin call modules entry points. obvious if `A[B]`, loader always try call `B_DllMain` before `A_DllMain` (except circular dependency when order of calls is undefined). but which modules will be in call graph ? all **X** dependency modules ? of course no. some of this modules can already be in memory (loaded) when we begin load **X**. so it entry points already called, with `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and must not be called second time now. this strategy used in xp, vista, win7:

when we load **X**:

1. load or locate in memory all it dependency modules
2. call entry points of **new** loaded (after **X**) modules only.
3. if `A[B]` - call `B_DllMain` before `A_DllMain`

example: loaded `X[Y[W[Z]], Z]`

```
//++begin load X
Z_DllMain
W_DllMain
Y_DllMain
X_DllMain
// --end load X
```

but this scenario not take in account next case - some module can be already in memory, but it entry point yet not called. how this can happen ? 
this can happen in case some module entry point call `LoadLibrary`.

example - loaded `X[Y<W[ Z]>, Z]`

```
//++begin load X
Y_DllMain
  //++begin load W
  W_DllMain
  //--end load W
Z_DllMain
X_DllMain
// --end load X
```

so `W_DllMain` will be called before `Z_DllMain`, despite `W[Z]`. exactly because this not recommended call `LoadLibrary` from DLL entry point.

---

but from Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices

> This can cause a deadlock or a crash.

the words about **deadlock not true** - of course any deadlock can not be basically. where ? how ? we already hold loader lock inside DLL entry point and this lock can be acquired recursively. crash really can be (before win8).

or another **false**:

> Call `ExitThread`. Exiting a thread during DLL detach can cause the
>   loader lock to be acquired again, causing a deadlock or a crash.

- **can** cause the loader lock to be acquired again - not **can** but **always**
- causing a deadlock - **false** - we already hold this lock
- a crash - no any crash will be, else one **false**

but which is really will be - thread exit without free loader lock. it became busy forever. as result any new thread creation or exit, any new DLL load or unload, or just `ExitProcess` call - hung, when try acquire loader lock. so deadlock here really will be, but not during Call `ExitThread` - latter.

and of course interesting note - the windows itself call `LoadLibrary` from `DllMain` - *user32.dll* always call `LoadLibrary` for *imm32.dll* from it entry point (still true and on win10)

---

but begin from win8 (or win8.1) loader became more smart on handle dependency modules. now **2** is changed

**2.** call entry points of **new** loaded (after X) modules or if module yet not initialized.

so in modern windows (8+) for load `X[Y<W[Z]>, Z]`

```
//++begin load X
Y_DllMain
  //++begin load W
  Z_DllMain
  W_DllMain
  //--end load W
X_DllMain
// -- end load X
```

the **Z** initialization will be moved to **W** load call graph. as result all will be correct now.

for test this we can build next solution: `test.exe[ kernel32, D1< D2[kernel32, msvcrt] >, msvcrt ]`

- **D2** import from **kernel32** and **msvcrt**  only and export `SomeFunc`
- **D1** import only from **kernel32** and call `LoadLibraryW(L"D2")` from it entry point, and then call `D2.SomeFunc`
- **test.exe** import from **kernel32**, **D1** and **msvcrt**

(exactly in this order ! this is critical important - **D1** must be **before** **msvcrt** in import, for this need set **D1** before **msvcrt** in linker command line)

as result **D1** entry point will be called before **msvcrt**. this is normal - **D1** not depends on **msvcrt**
but when **D1** load **D2** from it entry point, became interesting

code for **D2.dll** ( `/NODEFAULTLIB kernel32.lib msvcrt.lib` )

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl sprintf(PSTR buf, PCSTR format, ...);
}

BOOLEAN WINAPI MyEp( HMODULE , DWORD ul_reason_for_call, PVOID )
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("D2.DllMain\n");
    }

    return TRUE;
}

INT_PTR WINAPI SomeFunc()
{
    __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__))
    char buf[32];
    // this is only for link to msvcrt.dll
    sprintf(buf, "D2.SomeFunc\n");
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
    return 0;
}

#ifdef _WIN64
#define FuncName "?SomeFunc@@YA_JXZ"
#else
#define FuncName "?SomeFunc@@YGHXZ"
#endif

__pragma(comment(linker, "/export:" FuncName ",@1,NONAME,PRIVATE"))
```

code for **D1.dll** ( `/NODEFAULTLIB kernel32.lib` )

```
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4706)

BOOLEAN WINAPI MyEp( HMODULE hmod, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, PVOID )
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("D1.DllMain\n");
        if (hmod = LoadLibraryW(L"D2"))
        {
            if (FARPROC fp = GetProcAddress(hmod, (PCSTR)1))
            {
                fp();
            }
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

INT_PTR WINAPI SomeFunc()
{
    __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__))
    OutputDebugStringA("D1.SomeFunc\n");
    return 0;
}

#ifdef _WIN64
#define FuncName "?SomeFunc@@YA_JXZ"
#else
#define FuncName "?SomeFunc@@YGHXZ"
#endif

__pragma(comment(linker, "/export:" FuncName ",@1,NONAME"))
```

code for **exe** ( `/NODEFAULTLIB kernel32.lib D1.lib msvcrt.lib` )

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl sprintf(PSTR buf, PCSTR format, ...);
}

__declspec(dllimport) INT_PTR WINAPI SomeFunc();

void ep()
{
    char buf[32];
    // this is only for link to msvcrt.dll
    sprintf(buf, "exe entry\n");
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
    ExitProcess((UINT)SomeFunc());
}
```

output for xp:

```
LDR: D1.dll loaded - Calling init routine
D1.DllMain
Load: D2.dll
LDR: D2.dll loaded - Calling init routine
D2.DllMain
D2.SomeFunc
LDR: msvcrt.dll loaded - Calling init routine
exe entry
D1.SomeFunc
```

for win7:

```
LdrpRunInitializeRoutines - INFO: Calling init routine for DLL "D1.dll"
D1.DllMain
Load: D2.dll
LdrpRunInitializeRoutines - INFO: Calling init routine for DLL "D2.DLL"
D2.DllMain
D2.SomeFunc
LdrpRunInitializeRoutines - "msvcrt.dll"
exe entry
D1.SomeFunc
```

in both case call flow is the same - `D2.DllMain` called **before** *msvcrt* entry point, despite `D2[msvcrt]`

but on win8.1 and win10 - call flow is another:

```
LdrpInitializeNode - INFO: Calling init routine for DLL "D1.dll"
D1.DllMain
LdrpInitializeNode - INFO: Calling init routine for DLL "msvcrt.dll"
LdrpInitializeNode - INFO: Calling init routine for DLL "D2.DLL"
D2.DllMain
D2.SomeFunc
exe entry
D1.SomeFunc
```

the **D2** entry point called **after** **msvcrt** initialization.

so what is conclusion?

if when module `X[Y]` is loaded and no not initialized **Y** in memory - `Y_DllMain` will be called **before** `X_DllMain`. or in another words - if nobody call `LoadLibrary(X)` (or `LoadLibrary(Z[X])` ) from DLL entry point. so if your DLL will be loaded "normal" way (not by call `LoadLibrary` from `DllMain` or injected from driver on some dll load event) - you can be sure that crt entry point already called (crt initialized)

more - if you run on win8.1+ - and `X[Y]` is loaded - `Y_DllMain` will be always called **before** `X_DllMain`.

---

now about custom `/ENTRYPOINT` in your dll.

even if you use crt in separate DLLs - some small crt code will be statically linked to your module `DllMainCRTStartup` - which call your function `DllMain` (this is not a entry point) by name. so in case dynamic crt - we really have 2 crt parts - main part in separate DLLs and it will be initialized **before** your DLL entry point is called (*if not special case which i describe higher and win7,vista,xp*). and small static part (code inside your module). when this static part will be called already full depend from you. this part `DllMainCRTStartup` do some internal initializations, initialize global objects in your code (`initterm`) and call `DllMain`, after it return (on dll detach) call destructors for globals..

if you set custom entry point in DLL - at this point crt in separate DLLs already initialized, but your static crt no (as and global objects). from this custom entry point you will be need call `DllMainCRTStartup`